# Capture output of a batch file in powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

I need to capture the output created by a .bat file that is run from within a .ps1 file.

I'm new to powershell scripting but I know this isn't correct syntax. This best illustrates what I need to have happen.

I need to execute the facter.bat script then store its output in `$Body` so I can use that text later.

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\bin\facter.bat" > $Body
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

$Body = & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\bin\facter.bat"

Comment: It works, but there's a problem with this solution. Doing it this way only contains the standard output, but not the standard error too. Is there a way we can capture that too?

Comment: @PiyushSoni: 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

If you need to copy the output directly to another file, you can use the following command

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\bin\facter.bat" | Out-File -FilePath "<FilePathToWrite>.txt"
```